# Intercapedine si può utilizzare anche per indicare uno spazio esteso come una stanza?

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, word-choice, single-words, nouns

Da un po' di tempo mi sto chiedendo se effettivamente la parola **intercapedine** abbia un significato ambiguo. La definizione di cui mi interesso è la [seguente](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/intercapedine/), dal sito treccani.it:

> Spazio che separa due pareti o due superfici parallele o quasi; in
>   partic., in edilizia, il cunicolo che isola i muri degli scantinati
>   dal terreno circostante per impedire infiltrazioni d’acqua, o anche lo
>   spazio d’aria tra due pareti di mattoni o due vetri di un infisso, che
>   assicura l’isolamento termico o acustico.

Ho senz'altro compreso che l'intercapedine è *lo spazio tra due pareti*, ma non ho capito se una stanza si può considerare intercapedine, in quanto corrisponde comunque a uno spazio compreso tra due muri, ma risulta generalmente esteso rispetto alla definizione citata in corsivo.

Answer (score 2):

Titolo e testo della domanda non sono allineati:

> Intercapedine si può utilizzare anche per indicare uno spazio esteso come una stanza?

Sì, la dimensione di un'intercapedine è un particolare tecnico. Può esistere un'intercapedine "grossa come una stanza".

> una stanza si può considerare intercapedine?

Direi proprio di no, non si usa in questo senso e non l'ho mai sentito. La mia spiegazione è che la parola inizia con "inter-", cioè "interposto, messo in mezzo". Lo scopo principale di un'intercapedine è appunto separare due pareti (non necessariamenti muri), mentre lo scopo principale di una stanza, solitamente, è un altro.

E' vero che, specie in anni recenti, si parla di ambienti (stanze) concepite proprio per separarne altre, come per esempio l'*antibagno*; però anche in questo caso non credo che si possano definire intercapedini.

Comment: Il vocabolario Treccani riporta come etimologia: dal lat. intercapedo -dĭnis «interruzione», comp. di inter- e tema di capĕre «prendere»; inoltre nel link http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/intercapedine/ riporta: intercapedine: Nella tecnica delle costruzioni, con accezione generica, spazio che separa due superfici ravvicinate e per lo più parallele.

Comment: Il Nuovo De Mauro, per evitare fraintendimenti, parla di pareti “ravvicinate”: https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/intercapedine. La definizione di Wikipedia dice esplicitamente che è uno spazio non abitabile: https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercapedine.

Comment: @Benedetta grazie! La definizione di Wikipedia mi sembra migliore di quella del DeMauro: teoricamente un'intercapedine può anche essere molto larga per motivi tecnici, ma continua a rimanere un'intercapedine "messa *appositamente* in mezzo, e solo per quello scopo".